# IOS TextField SetText

Tags: ios

I have 2 class. In first class I use `didSelectrowAtIndexPath:` method. In second class I have textfield. I create string in `didSelectrowAtIndexPath:` method. I want to set textfield text when I click tableview cell then open second view. But when I click row firstly run second class's `viewdidload:` before `didselect` method. And my string get nil value.

How can fix that problem ?

[EDİT]

Solve it. With [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NMzLNODGhyI) tutorial.

Comment: I'm looking fastly and i will write result. Thanks for idea!

Comment: Provide some code, so we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use prepareforsegue: method to pass the data from viewcontroller A to B on click on tableview cell

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers) :

Comment: I tried it and works. Thank you.